# How to display images with different heights on multiple lines stick to each other

Tags: html, css, image

I am using masonry.js now bt still unable to get the desired effect.

Javascript:`

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {columnWidth: 200, itemSelector: '.item'});
```

`

CSS: `

```
html, body, div, img {padding:0; margin:0; border:0;}
.container {width:100%;}
.item {width:19.5%;display:inline-block; margin-right:-3px;}
.item img{width:100%; vertical-align:top;}
```

`

HTML: `

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
<div class="item">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x100">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x350">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x350">
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
</div>
</div>
```

`
The output is right now like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74143916/imageplacement.png

My requirement is somewhat like this below image.

[image]

Comment: Try **[Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**

Comment: Thank you Paulie_D, I have had a look at this javascript mentioned above. Looks pretty simple, let me try and see the result.

Comment: I am using the masonry.js bt still the I m not getting the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wookmark jquery plugin will solve your problem. It supports responsive view also.
http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Comment: Looks much similar to above suggestion Masonary.js, Will have to try both the scripts and see which one give me the best result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to css and can use Javascript, the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin is worth a try. It has worked for me quite well.